# Can Application Insights be added to a .NET 4.0 DLL ?

Tags: azure, dll, azure-application-insights

It says it is not supported. The DLL is used by Encompass 360 product. It would be nice to have Application Insights on all my projects but they are class libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*what* says it is not supported?  do you mean from the Application Insights built-in support in Visual Studio?

In that case, yes, we don't know how to auto add it, wire it up like we would for the other project types.

However, you can always just add the base

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/1.1.0

package to your project yourself from nuget package manager / manage nuget packages in VS.  You'll have to do the manual hookups yourself to set your instrumentation key, but the package itself fully supports .net assemblys.

Comment: Iused the GUI and this particular nugget package does not show up.. But I see the ones for .web and .windows.

Comment: Last version to support 4.0 was 2.4.0

Answer (score 2):

4.0 is supported. If you open [Application Insights API nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/1.1.0) you will see that it supports 4.0, 4.5 and win phone target frameworks. Beta version of this nuget as well supports dnxcore 5.0.